# Mongo Aggregation Project add property to all in Array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

Im using mongo 2.6 and as part of a aggregations pipeline I need to add a an object to all entries in an array. Since I use mongo 2.6 i cant use $addFields.

My data looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a290637e4b08ddd7334e541"),
"placeName" : "Caspeco Mobile Order",
"created" : ISODate("2017-12-07T09:13:27.248Z"),
"currency" : "SEK",
"isCredit" : false,
"costCenter" : {
    "name" : "Test Restaurangen",
    "number" : "800"
},
"debitAccounts" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "CASH",
        "number" : "1915",
        "amount" : 189.0
    }
],
"creditAccounts" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Mat",
        "number" : "3120",
        "amount" : 168.749984741211
    }
],
"taxAccounts" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Moms 12%",
        "number" : "2621",
        "amount" : 20.2500076293945
    }
],
"credit" : false
```

}

And as first step in aggregations I need to add the costCenter object to all potential creditAccounts

Doing something like:

```
{$project: {'creditAccounts'{'costCentre':'$costCenter.name','costCentreAccount':'$costCenter.number','name':'$creditAccounts.name','number':'$creditAccounts.number','amount':'$creditAccounts.amount'}, document: '$$ROOT'}}
```

Doent work since it generates a array of names and numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to be $map:

```
creditAccounts:{$map:{input:'$creditAccounts', as:'creditAcccount', in : {name:'$$creditAcccount.name',number:'$$creditAcccount.name',amount:'$$creditAcccount.amount', costCentre:'$costCenter.name',costCentreAccount:'$costCenter.number'}}}
```

Even though its really ugly.